# Classe "Mage_Chronorelais_Helper_Data'" não encontrada no Magento

Tags: magento

Apaguei um módulo no Magento e o seguinte erro surgiu:

> [14-Oct-2014 11:42:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Chronorelais_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 548

A função é a seguinte:

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

A linha 548 é a seguinte:

```
self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
```

No backup que fiz antes de apagar o módulo, procuro por "Mage_Chronorelais_Helper_Data" e não encontro nada, procuro na base de dados algo relacionado e não encontro nada.

Como resolver o erro?

Comment: ele esta tentando instanciar um helper que nao existe mais por algum motivo voce removeu ele

Comment: @Otto certo, mas como remover essa instância? Procurei em todo lado pela classe e não encontro, nem na base de dados. Tem que existir em algum lado de alguma forma algo que leve o sistema a tentar criar a instância, isso que não estou a entender.

Answer (score 1):

**dentro de:**

```
public static function helper($name)
{
```

**coloque assim:**

```
public static function helper($name)
{

echo $name; die;
```

**assim você acha o nome real do helper que esta sendo chamado e consegue consultar quem esta chamando ele e o remove caso necessário.**

Comment: Fiz isso e o resultado foi "core/http" mas não consegui entender o que realmente isso quer dizer.

Comment: é que eu esqueci que tem vários helpers sendo chamados ali ... tira o die veja se acha algo sobre o q voce quer

Comment: sim, fiz isso sem o die e o último que aparece antes do erro é o "core/http".

Comment: faz o seguinte amigo coloca novamente o modulo e desativa ele somente no xml assim seria primeiramente o passo correto

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso, mas tenho mesmo que remove-lo, uma vez que o modulo está em francês e instalei o modulo em português, se deixar os dois o modulo em PT não funciona.

Comment: nao da para deixar o fr desativado e ativar somente o pt ?

Comment: Não, está gerando conflitos e acaba por não funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Felipe,

Se estiver usando **linux**:

```
grep -ril 'chronorelais' app/code/
```

**caso não** dê um find no projeto todo **pela IDE** que está utilizando, com certeza essa instância está sendo gerada em algum arquivo/classe.

Com isso vc sabe qual o arquivo e remove a criação da instância.

Abs